# Why does .Net care when an assembly was built?

Tags: .net

We had a situation where we were having issues with a DLL that was build in our office which is located in the Central time zone and then deployed onto a server located on the west coast (Pacific time zone).  We'd have issues with "UTCDate out of range" when trying to retrieve embedded resources from our DLL (via WebResource.axd).  Once we discovered this and updated the DLL's file time to match the web server's time, everything worked fine.

My question is: Why does .Net care when an assembly was built?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior connected to [WebResource.axd caching algorithm](http://www.geekytidbits.com/webresource-axd-throwing-argumentoutofrangeexception/).
Also you can look at nice [touch solution of this problem](http://alexpinsker.blogspot.com/2008/06/argumentoutofrangeexception-at.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the time the file was created is used to see if the file needs to be replaced when building a solution. Other than that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the assemblies over a network share, then there are various security issues that .NET takes into account.  You might want to look into [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28VS.71%29.aspx)